# Unable to build maven module with jar packaging under Maven Project...!

Tags: maven

am not able to build the maven maodule with jar packaging. am getting error as

```
Could not calculate build plan: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): ConnectException
```

my machine is tagged to company network, is their any proxy issue? I tried creating settings.xml with the below:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  <usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry>
  <offline>false</offline>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers/>
  <mirrors/>
  <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |-->
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>      
      <host>proxy.tcs.com</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|google.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>

  </proxies>
  <profiles/>
  <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

Am able to create sub module with pom packaging but not with jar,Pls suggest

If i try to update the Maven Project config, console is displayed as below:

```
2/27/13 1:08:12 PM IST: Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
2/27/13 1:08:12 PM IST: Updating index central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
2/27/13 1:11:37 PM IST: Refreshing settings C:\Users\346496\.m2\settings.xml
2/27/13 1:50:58 PM IST: Update started
2/27/13 1:50:59 PM IST: Update completed: 0 sec
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Update started
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Generating sources /common/pom.xml
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Build error for /common/pom.xml; org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.pom
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Failed to determine compiler source setting, assuming default
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Failed to determine compiler target setting, assuming default
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Failed to determine compiler source setting, assuming default
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Failed to determine compiler target setting, assuming default
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Failed to determine compiler test inclusions, assuming defaults
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Failed to determine compiler test exclusions, assuming defaults
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Failed to determine compiler inclusions, assuming defaults
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Failed to determine compiler exclusions, assuming defaults
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Adding source folder /common/src/main/java
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Adding resource folder /common/src/main/resources
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Adding source folder /common/src/test/java
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Adding resource folder /common/src/test/resources
2/27/13 1:51:04 PM IST: Update completed: 0 sec
```

I have configured Maven link `http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e` with eclipse version Juno and Jdk 1.7.
I tried all the possible solutions from net, but didnot succeed.

Comment: Do you have access to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 ?

Comment: nope, when i hit the url, its saying as: Browsing for this directory has been disabled.

View this directory's contents on http://search.maven.org instead.

Comment: if the above link is blocked by the company, it will dispaly as company blocked the site.

Comment: sorry, can you browse this : http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.4.3/

Comment: So, you can try to clean your local repo in C:\Users\346496\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-resources-plugin\ , deleting the content might solve your issue

Comment: i have tried deleting the maven-resources-plugin folder and also whole contents of repository folder.. nothing worked..:-(

Comment: And you have the issue from command line (mvn clean install on your project) as well ?

Comment: i have installed maven directly in eclipse, if i point to the project folder, its not at all identifying the mvn command

Comment: Apparently a lot of users experienced problem with this approach of "Maven into Eclipse". I think having a proper maven installed is more reliable

Comment: i installed mav with the http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e link directly into eclipse, also i thru eclipse market place i installed, both ways same issue

Comment: I was thinking about a standard maven installation : http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: ya i ve downloaded the maven to my local machine, and added to the environment path variable, can u pls guide how do i configure the same to eclipse

Comment: Can you run mvn clean install in a console, for your project ?

Comment: again build unsuccessful:

Comment: [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (D:\EclipseWorkspace\iON27Feb2013). Please verify you invoked
 Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProject

Comment: You must run it from your project's directory (where your POM is )

Comment: Hi, I was able to compile my code by adding username and pwd to the proxies in settings.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with the proxy settings, since we use the proxy network in the company Maven was unable to download its plugins properly, So added settings.xml file with the proxy settings, worked fine.